# How to combine input and HTTP get in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to combine input text with HTTP get. I tried some methods it works but it' doesn't what I want. I have some URL like this `http://localhost/web.php?tN=false&f5=kaka`
in `f5` get some data from input in HTML. This my HTML

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Username</span>
        <input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder=" Username" name="loginname" type="text" ng-model="loginData.username" ng-click="submitFunction()" required>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Password</span>
        <input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder=" Password" name="password" type="password" ng-model="loginData.password" required>
    </label>
</div>
```

and this my controller

```
$scope.submitFunction = function() {
    kaka.falselogin($scope.loginData.username).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

My problem is that I  must click after input in form username to get data. It's complicated if I must get data after input in form username
anyone has an idea ? Please help me to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: try ng-change. also debounce all elements which trigger a digest cycle.

Comment: yeah it work thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `ng-change` directive.
It'll run the provided function whenever the input`s value changed.

```
<input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder=" Username" name="loginname" type="text" ng-model="loginData.username" ng-change="submitFunction()" required>
```

Considering you issue HTTP requests on each change, you'd basically flood the server.
To solve that issue you can debounce the model so that it takes `x` ms until the new value will be applied.

```
ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }'
```

In combination it would look like this:

```
<input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder=" Username" name="loginname" type="text" ng-model="loginData.username" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }' ng-change="submitFunction()" required>
```

There you go :)

Comment: Thanks it helpful